# How do I move particular rows to the end of my matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with some empty rows and empty columns. I'd like to move the empty rows and columns all the way to the end of the matrix on the right and bottom.

I've managed to obtain the rownames and columnnames for all the empty rows.

What i tried to do:

1. Make a for loop to delete off all the rows and columns based on index (which doesn't work because the order of the empty rows changes after every delete, so I abandoned this idea)
2. Delete the rows based on the property of the row names.

`Cnew = Cnew[!(Cnew$rownames %in% empty_rownames)]`

Can't seem to get it to work though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have a 6x6 matrix with one empty column and one empty row (meaning all their entries are `NA`)

```
Cnew <- matrix(nrow = 6, ncol = 6, data = 1)

Cnew[,4] <- NA
Cnew[3,] <- NA

empty.columns <- which(colSums(Cnew, na.rm = TRUE) == 0)
empty.rows <- which(rowSums(Cnew, na.rm = TRUE) == 0)

# we first delete the row and cols

# for deleting do
Cdel <- Cnew[-empty.rows,-empty.columns]

# and then paste the rows and cols at the edges again
Cdel <- cbind(Cdel, rep(NA, length(empty.columns)))
Cdel <- rbind(Cdel, rep(NA, length(empty.rows)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If only for deleting rows (observations) with NA values in some of the columns

```
test <-matrix( 
     c(rep(c(NA, 1:9), 8)  ), 
     nrow=10, 
     ncol=8) 
test <- test[complete.cases(test),]
```